# Azure Static Websites encoding apostrophes and other characters in a weird way

Tags: html, azure, encoding, azure-static-website-hosting

Here's what this text looks like when I load the HTML locally in Chrome:

[image]

On the contrary, here's what it looks like rendered after I publish to Azure Static Websites:

[image]

Apostrophes, quotations, and other characters are being rendered as some weird text.

What's the cause of this? Why does it happen only when published? Seems like an Azure bug to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check if you have this line in the head section

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```